# blurry images with mogrify & convert

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, png

Does anyone know why this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpFzL.png) is so blurry?

I did a convert from pdf to png and it turned out like that. Before deleting imagemagick and it's entire toolset from *software-center* most of my image programs were displaying like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFL6S.png). Now for the most part it's just blurry, though a couple still display like that such as gimp. I am running in xfce maybe it's to do with the distribution enviornment. Main issue is the absurd blurriness. I reinstalled all additional packages that were available for imagemagick in the *software-center*

I use `convert *.pdf *.png` & `mogrify -format png *.pdf` to convert

Now on the other hand if I converted the file to djvu and converted that to a tif. The images have no problem converting. More so it does not generate an oversized tif file of around 25mb compared to 3mb with djvu which is super clear & no blurriness.

Comment: Can you provide the original one so I can work on it.

Comment: I have experimented with converting PDF to different formats in the  past and I have found Inkscape's CLI to offer the most accurate results. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15484727).

Comment: When you open (view) your file, ensure your zoom is 100 %; else you will see distortions. @Seth who says you can't read it at 100 % ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the density variable.

```
convert -density 400 *.pdf *.png
```

Comment: Not sure why this would be downvoted... The trick to avoiding blurry images definitely seems to be getting the right density setting.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but maybe because the syntax is wrong and won't work if you have more than one png file in your directory.  Use "convert -density 400 file.pdf file.png" for a single file or "mogrify -density 400 -format png *.pdf" if you want to convert multiple pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

I'll plagiarize the answer I just posted to [a related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42856/how-can-i-convert-a-png-to-a-pdf-in-high-quality-so-its-not-blurry-or-fuzzy).

It can be very complicated to get good pdf output from `convert`. Try [`img2pdf`](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf/blob/master/README.md) instead. From the readme:

> Lossless conversion of images to PDF without unnecessarily re-encoding JPEG and JPEG2000 files. Thus, no loss of quality and no unnecessary large output file.